# Is it possible to add/play audio from the external storage (/storage/emulated/0) in Android Studio using the GvrAudioEngine API?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-vr-sdk

I want to play audio from an external folder (music/data or any other) using the [GvrAudioEngine API](https://developers.google.com/vr/reference/android/com/google/vr/sdk/audio/GvrAudioEngine) by Google VR in an Android Studio App. However, I am unable to do so. The only thing that seems to work is an audio file placed in the Assets folder. However, that does not serve my problem.
**Is there any workaround to solve the problem?**
**Or is there any other Library/API I could use for spatial audio rendering?**

### Code is as follows:

```
GvrAudioEngine gvrAudioEngine = new GvrAudioEngine(this, GvrAudioEngine.RenderingMode.BINAURAL_HIGH_QUALITY);
String SOUND_FILE = "cube_sound.wav"  // Preload the sound file  
gvrAudioEngine.preloadSoundFile(SOUND_FILE); // Create the 'sourceId' sound object. // You can create multiple sound objects using the same sound file. 
int sourceId = gvrAudioEngine.createSoundObject(SOUND_FILE);
```

where cube_sound.wav is located in the Assets Folder (this works)
However, if I replace the SOUND_FILE with an external storage path(/storage/emulated/0/cube_sound.wav), I get `sourceId` = -1 (Invalid). I have ensured that the audio file is located at this place.